# react-google-maps align MarkerWithLabel horizontally

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, marker, react-google-maps

I want to create a marker with a label above, and later on make it so I can click the marker and it opens up info boxes. I have:

```
<MarkerWithLabel labelAnchor={{x: 0, y: 25}} icon={marker_icons[post.type]} key={post.id} position={{lat: post.location.lat, lng: post.location.lon}}>
    <div style={{fontSize: 14}}>{post.prefix + " " + post.name}</div>
</MarkerWithLabel>
```

Currently it looks like the left but I want to align the label to look like the right one, how would I be able to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *align* label the following option could be considered:

- specify label container (`div`) `width` and set `text-align` to `center` via `labelStyle` property
- set `labelAnchor` property based on label container width

The following example displays label on top of marker and label content vertically aligned to center

```
const Map = (props) => {

    const labelSize = { width: 220};
    const labelPadding = 8;

    return (
      <GoogleMap 
        defaultZoom={props.zoom}
        defaultCenter={props.center}
      >
        {props.places.map(place => {
          return (
            <MarkerWithLabel
              labelStyle={{ textAlign: "center", width:labelSize.width + 'px', backgroundColor: "#7fffd4", fontSize: "14px", padding:  labelPadding + "px"}}
              labelAnchor={{ x: (labelSize.width/2) + labelPadding , y: 80 }}
              key={place.id}
              position={{ lat: place.lat, lng: place.lng }}>
              <span>{place.name}</span>
            </MarkerWithLabel>
          );
        })}
      </GoogleMap>
    );
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jvj0z8wwpv)

Comment: Thanks! All I had to do to make it work is to subtract 18px-ish from the labelAnchor.x as I am using svg icons, otherwise it is a bit off.

Comment: Update! Instead of doing that I just fixed my SVG images by editing them so the centre is at the top left corner so they are properly centered.

Comment: what about React 18? This doesn't work in React 18 anymore

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that is using `@react-google-maps/api` instead of 
 `react-google-maps` module
 
*Yes, they are different npm packages, I think*

Anyways,
`<Marker/>` component has this prop

Here's how I did it:

```
<Marker
  label={"Label onTop? pls"}

  icon={{
    url: "some_img_link",
    labelOrigin: new maps.Point(25, -10),
  }}

  position={{
    lat: 26.259,
    lng: -80.27,
  }}
/>
```

If you're a noob like me and you're wondering how I knew about `labelOrigin` well, these fancy libraries... and I hope they use Google's API.

Here's a link to that stuff:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Icon.labelOrigin

Good luck to you